# SQLite update with join not possible, what do I use?

Tags: sqlite, t-sql, sql-update, inner-join

I have a table as follows:

```
ID   Col_A    Col_B

1    P-1      123
2    S        123
3    P-3      456
4    S        456
```

ID is the primary key.

What I want to do is concatenate the ID of rows 1 and 3 to Col_A of rows 2 and 4, based on Col_B equivalence. In other words, where Col_A = 'S', find the ID of the row with the same value in Col_B, and add that ID to Col_A.

The result would be:

```
1    P-1    123
2    S-1    123
3    P-3    456
4    S-3    456
```

Could someone please show me how to write this query in SQLite, I am having no success.

In SQL server I use an inner join on the same table, and this works:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.Col_A = 'S-' + CAST(B.ID as VARCHAR(24)) 
FROM Table1 A
INNER JOIN Table1 B ON
A.Col_B = B.Col_B 
WHERE A.Col_A = 'S';
```

As far as I can tell you can't use a join in SQLite within an update, but have no idea what to do instead.

I have tried:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Col_A = 'S' || (SELECT B.ID from Table1 B WHERE B.Col_B = Col_B)
WHERE Col_A = 'S';
```

This results in:

```
1    P-1    123
2    S-1    123
3    P-3    456
4    S-1    456
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a table prefix, `Col_B` refers to the innermost table where this column name can be found. In this case, this would be `Table1 B`.

To refer to the outer table, you must use its name: `Table1.Col_B`:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Col_A = 'S' || (SELECT B.ID from Table1 B WHERE B.Col_B = Table1.Col_B)
WHERE Col_A = 'S';
```

Comment: CL would you mind writing out the query, so I can see exactly what you mean? I have tried various versions of table prefixes, and they all have the same result. The 'join' is on the same table, so it's confusing.